# Do I need to get an actuator for installing a keyless entry system on a honda jazz/fit 2003 (GD) with manual central locking?

Tags: honda, keyless-entry, jazz

I have a honda jazz 2003. It has manual central locking, meaning: I can lock/unlock all doors via:

1. the driver's door lock
2. the plastic pin on top of the driver's door panel.

It doesn't have one of those lock/unlock buttons on the door panel, next to the windows buttons, or anywhere else.

I'm unsure if I need to buy and install an actuator for the driver's door, or a remote & receiver kit would be enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I do need get an extra actuator.

I took the actuator (part #25 on the diagram) out from inside the driver's door this morning and it turns out that the parts to make it functional are missing. In other words, it's only an empty plastic shell of an actuator except for the mechanical switch in there, no electric motor and connector.

[image]
[image]